# Defining the integral on an arbitrary metric space

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, integral-operators

I am trying to prove a version of [Mercer's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer's_theorem) for an arbitrary compact metric space; that is, I do not wish to restrict myself to the space of real-valued continuous functions $C[a,b]$. I understand the proof for the case of $C[a,b]$, but for the arbitrary metric space case, I need to define integration in that arbitrary space.

In other words, given compact metric spaces $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$, and let $f:X\rightarrow Y$. How can we define the integral

$$\displaystyle\int_X f(x)dx$$

so that it is well-defined no matter what our choice of $X$ and $Y$ is?

Are there any resources that explain this clearly and fully? I have a pretty solid understanding of basic functional analysis and some understanding of point-set topology. I think this is related to Measure Theory, but I'm not sure exactly how or where to start.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? If $Y$ is truly an arbitrary compact metric space we may have no arithmetical operators on it and it would be very strange to speak of integrals I think. If you can give $X$ a measure and $Y$ is a Banach space (far from arbitrary metric space) we have the Bochner integral.

Comment: Yes, you definitely need some notion of "sum" in $Y$ or some extension of $Y$...

Comment: To be honest, I was not sure how general we could make $Y$ and still have the integral make sense. I do want $X$ to remain pretty general (i.e. not just the reals). I think I can work with the Bochner integral, though, for my purposes. Are there any resources that explain it besides wikipedia?

Answer (score 6):

A simple example of why this is headed in a wrong direction: If $X=\mathbb [0,1]$ and $Y_1=[0,1]$, then the integral might be defined as normal. If $Y_2=[-1/2,1/2]$, then the integral defined as normal also exists. But, as metric spaces without knowing their "real number" structure, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are essentially the same metric space, but the integral returns a radically different value.

Essentially, there is not a canonical integral even in the case $X=[0,1]$ and $Y$ being isomorphic to $[0,1]$ as a metric space.

You need much more structure than merely being compact metric spaces.